# Copying a Previous number from Numbered list doc

Tags: ms-word

I am working in HotDocs, a document template creation software. I am looking for a way to insert a previous number into the template, as it's a legal form and need to say "Paragraphs 1 - _ are true." The number can change depending on conditions, so was wondering if there's a way for Word to copy the number in. If not we can write it in. I will add some screen shots
[image]

I would need the 72 to fill in the highlighted space, but that number can change because there are several different special counts that fill in on conditions. Any ideas for how to do this? I could reformat the numbered list as a field so that I have more control over it, but there are other issues with that that I don't feel would be worth the effort. Thank you!

The HotDocs scripting language being used has basic coding capabilities, IF statements and loops and more.

Comment: You have enough reputation that you should know the site guidelines for posting questions. As your question stands, it's at the end-user level and should be asked elsewhere. If you want code, you need to provide more information, as described in the [help]. And you should indicate the programming language to be used. FWIW bookmarks and REF fields might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have an answer to this, I would try a cross-reference. Open the original template, and select Insert | Cross-reference in the Links group on the Insert tab. If your numbered item is formatted properly, it will appear on the Numbered item reference list in the Cross-reference dialog, and you can select it. Then, even if the position or number of the source paragraph change, the link to the destination location should remain true. Use F9 to update the fields.